# 2010 - Attachments not appearing on blog post view

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

We are using the 2010 out of the box blog implementation, and we're using emails with attachments to submit posts. Although the list shows that each post item has an attachment, in the standard blog view, there is no option to view attached documents. I'm wondering what the typical solution would be to show attachments in a standard blog view.

Thanks.

Comment: So the attachment is available in the Edit view but not in the display view of the form?

Comment: Yes, I believe so.